Are all dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure zero countable?
In the paper "Measure and Cardinality", Briggs and Schaffter  prove that if a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality less than the continuum, then it has Lebesgue measure zero.
With this result, we know that in the model of ZFC + $\neg$CH we can always construct a dense set with measure zero that is not countable.
Firstly I want to know if there is any immediate counter-example for the statement made in the title. If not, is it true and possible to prove it in ZFC + CH?
Edit:I also found Do sets with positive Lebesgue measure have same cardinality as R?.

Do you know about ternary Cantor set?

just take any dense null set union the cantor set.

Your first sentence is not correct. What is true is that every measurable set of size less than continuum has measure zero.

No. Take any uncountable measure zero set (say, the Cantor set) and consider the union of that set and $\mathbb{Q}$. The result will be dense but uncountable.

My favorite example is $C+\mathbb Q:=\{c+q\mid c\in C,\ q\in\mathbb Q\} = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q} (C+q),$ where $C$ is the ordinary ternary Cantor set.
$C$ is uncountable, not dense, and has Lebesgue measure zero. $\mathbb Q$ is everywhere countably dense. $C+\mathbb Q$ is everywhere uncountably dense, but still has Lebesgue measure zero since it's a countable union of sets with measure zero.
